# Divide integer by unsigned long - is there a compile time error/warning?

Tags: c++, math

I get an answer of -496307337. What is wrong in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
     int displacement_sum_x = -4500;
     unsigned long cluster_size = 900;
     //... with some calculation the value of displacement_sum_x is -4500.
     displacement_sum_x /= cluster_size;
     std::cout << displacement_sum_x;
}
```

Can someone explain the process of the conversion here?

EDIT: 
I found out that a typecast needs to be done at `displacement_sum_x /= (int)cluster_size;` and then the code works.

Is there a way, wherein I can use some kind of c++ warning / error, so that I get the problem at the compile time? The gcc compiler with usual settings, did not complain about this.

Comment: It's probably that the int is being promoted to unsigned long for the operation, and negatives don't turn out well, as you know, as unsigned values. The cout still treats the value as int, and that's the value you see. If you want to properly see the right result, use the same type on both.

Comment: -4500 gets converted to signed long -4500, which gets converted to unsigned long (some big number), which gets divided by 900, and put back into displacement_sum_x (slicing high order value if unsigned long and int are of different size).

Comment: To avoid the unexpected don't mix `signed` and `unsigned` in the same expression.

Comment: Check out the documentation for `-Wsign-compare`, `-Wconversion` & `-Wsign-conversion`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to cast the value in order to do the operation:

`displacement_sum_x /= (int) cluster_size;`

The gcc options `-Wconversion` and `-Wsign-conversion` should help to see the issue.

You can get more info about the warning options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you should be avoiding the mixing of signed and unsigned values in the same expression (*especially* when there are negative numbers involved). In your case, the operation:

```
displacement_sum_x /= cluster_size;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
displacement_sum_x = displacement_sum_x / cluster_size;
```

In the expression above, since the operands to operator `/` are different (`int`/`unsigned long`), the `int` is [promoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to an `unsigned long`, which here is a very large value. That result is then divided by 5, and downcasted back to an integer (A good compiler should warn you of the signed/unsigned mismatch). To solve, just change this sort of expression so that `cluster_size` is initialized as an integer or add a cast it to an integer using [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) (I recommend the previous).

Here is an [example](https://repl.it/repls/UnwrittenSplendidCoypu) that illustrates this.

Answer (score -1):

Problem Lies here in your code

displacement_sum_x /= cluster_size;

Points
1) You are dividing like (unsigned long) / (int)

2) Since division requires same data type so the int is promoted to unsigned long

3) The value (int displacement_sum_x = -4500 ) is converted to unsigned long which will be equal to 4294962796

4) Then the division takes place with it as 4294962796 / 900 = 4772180.88444

5) And the result will be 4772180 since it integral not a floating type.

Comment: have a look at @Arnav answer  above. The result is already mentioned in the question, so this answer ( with a wrong result ) has no meaning.